# Unable to use DateTime.AddTicks

Tags: c#, datetime

I am trying to add ticks to a DateTime (c#), but I can't figure out why is this not working:

```
DateTime end = StartTime.AddTicks(timer.Interval);
Console.WriteLine(StartTime.ToLocalTime() + " + " + timer.Interval + " = " + end.ToLocalTime());
```

This is giving me the following output :

```
24/05/2014 20:47:27 + 60000 = 24/05/2014 20:47:27
```

So, why is *end* the same value than *StartTime* ?

FYI, I declared my variables like this :

```
private DateTime StartTime;
private Timer timer = new Timer();
```

Comment: `Timer.Interval` is milliseconds. But ticks are not milliseconds, they are something much smaller. You're mixing apples and oranges. I think you should be using `DateTime.AddMilliseconds` instead of `DateTime.AddTicks`.

Comment: If you want an interval, you might want to look at the Stopwatch class instead of the Timer. Here's a good overview of the differences: http://robertgreiner.com/2010/06/using-stopwatches-and-timers-in-net/

Comment: Yes, it was indeed quite stupid to add a millisecond value(60000) with AddTicks which adds ... ticks, not milliseconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

10.000 ticks make 1ms, 60.000 ticks make 6ms, you don't display millisecond part so there is no difference in output, but values are different.

If you change your output formatting to the following (display millisecond part), then you can see the difference.

```
Console.WriteLine(StartTime.ToLocalTime().ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff") + " + " + timer.Interval + " = " + end.ToLocalTime().ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff"));
```

More about ticks: [DateTime.Ticks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.ticks.aspx)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I don't know why I was actually thinking that 1 tick = 1 ms.